# ASP Force download txt file sending back source instead

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function in ASP that returns a TXT file.

I want the user to download the file but the browser wanted to keep displaying it when I did `Response.Redirect("/Dir/Dir/TextFilePath.txt");`

So I discovered that if you add this to the header it forces a download

```
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
                      "attachment;filename=/Dir/Dir/TextFilePath.txt");
```

And this DOES force download the file, with one catch.

The file is the aspx source code and not my txt file.... It's named correctly but it is most definitely not the txt file.

Comment: Surely it's up to the client/browser with they want to save it to disk or display it. Why would you need to force them to?

Comment: Its not up to the client/browser, it's up to me. I don't want their browser to redirect to a text filled page... I want it to stay on the current page and download the file. That's not the problem though. The problem as I said is that it returns source code and not the txt file I pointed it at

Comment: it usually happens when you forget to add the file type and size header

Comment: Thanks @Banana I think this got me closer

Comment: I believe adding that header tells the browser that the page it is added to (your ASPX) is an attachment called TextFilePath.txt.  To get what you want, you'd need to have a similar header included when your web-server returned the text file itself.  You probably cannot just include the header in the text file (because the webserver probably adds the headers and separating line for you).  You _might_ be able get what you want if the rest of the ASP that includes the AddHeader could include the contents of the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a correct way to download files in asp.net.
note the 'a correct way' and not 'the correct way', you can do it in other ways but this one works for me.

```
try
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + _Filename);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Word");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _FileLength_in_bytes);
    Response.BinaryWrite(_Filedata_bytes);
    Response.End();
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{ }
finally
{
}
```

the example above transmits a word file by sending it as a byte array.
you dont have to do it this way, but it works.

also i would like to add for anyone who decides to use my method, 
this **WILL** throw a `ThreadAbortException` at `Response.End()`.
its a known issue and it affects nothing, everything is being executed correctly but the exception is still thrown, so it must be caught.

Comment: Yup what I came up with is something fairly close to this. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can't affect the headers of the URL supplied for the redirect from the page where the redirect was issued from. I suspect that you  actually want to do something like:

```
var responseText = 
     File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Dir/Dir/TextFilePath.txt"));
Response.ContentType="text/plain";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                   "attachment;filename=TextFilePath.txt");
Response.Output.Write(responseText);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
this.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file);

Response.TransmitFile( Server.MapPath(fileName) );
Response.End();
```